# google data api auth without raising user form login

Tags: php, oauth, gdata, picasa, zend-gdata

I'm building an web which will get data from picasa. Several people will use. The web is just have 1 data source (1 picasa account) but I want to make the user authorized into that account without raising google form login page. I know that there is a solution using Zend_GData package, but from this site https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/code they say that API Versions Supported by the Client Library is v1. The google developer say that I should use Oauth 2.

Is it possible to make the several user use 1 data source (from 1 picasa account), without raising google form login? (the user can edit, delete, and add the source)

thx

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with php then only version 1 is supported so use that only..

with oauth 2 you will not going to perform the operations which you can perform using Zend_GData..

and it is not possible to acess data with-out login.